# Why can't I use tuple packing in a Python lambda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, return, tuples

When I try the following in Python:

```py
>>> lambda x: x, x * 2, x * 3
```

It gives a `NameError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Why doesn't this work when it does work inside regular functions, like in the below code?

```
def function(x):
    return x, x * 2, x * 3

function(1)  # Returns (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: `lambda x:(x,x*2, x*3)`

Comment: @sahasrara62 my answer contains a similar snippet

Comment: @sahasrara62 I added your snippet as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you have to remember that lambdas are functions, and functions are first-class citizens. That means you can use them like any other object, including putting them in tuples. As it turns out, Python is trying to use tuple packing, just not in the way you expect. See the following code snippet:

```
>>> lambda: 1, 2, 3
(<function <lambda> at 0x000001A944F2F040>, 2, 3)
```

As you can see, it is packing the lambda into a tuple! As you might expect, this is because it is easier to explicitly return a tuple (i.e. `lambda: (1, 2, 3)`, or `lambda x: (x, x * 2, x * 3)`) then to change the Python syntax altogether (which already packs lambdas into tuples, rather than tuples into lambdas).